# How do you filter out traffic from your own IP address in Google Analytics when using IP Anonymization?

Tags: google, google-analytics, ip-address, filtering, google-tag-manager

I'm using Universal Analytics via Googe Tag Manager. I want to filter out my own IP in a view.

Since I'm using [IP address anonymization](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2763052?hl=en), I'm filtering both my full and my IP ending with 0. (e.g. 1.2.3.4 and 1.2.3.0).

The problem is that I can still see my own traffic. I can test this using the realtime view in Google Analytics and I also see my own traffic in results.

Can anyone suggest how to properly filter out my own IP traffic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best and easiest way to do this is from within your application instead of from within Google Analytics. Easiest way is to add a switch to your code to detect if you are connecting to your own site (which can be detected anyway you wish really) and if you are detected then don't add the Google Analytics code to the page at all, otherwise add it no problems. We use this ourselves. Connections from within our own network don't have the Google Analytics code added to the websites but connections from the public gateway have Google Analytics added.

Comment: Thanks, i've already added logic for this as I couldn't find a solution thats GTM based.